# Java Collections HashMap, value changes unexpectedly

Tags: java

```
public class ListMap {
    HashMap<Integer, List> mp = new HashMap();
    List myList = new ArrayList();
    Integer x = 0;
    Integer y = 5;

    void test() {
    for(Integer i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        x = y;
        myList.add("check-1a" + i);
        myList.add("check-1a" + i + 1);
        y = null;
        System.out.println(x); // output=5
        mp.put(i, myList);
        myList.clear();
    }
}
```

1) But after clearing the List with `myList.clear()` the values that was inside the Map also gets cleared.

I mean to say that the map `key` remains there but it contains an "empty" List

2) However regarding the Objects `x` & `y`, after setting `y` to `null` how come `x` doesn't change?

Comment: Don't use raw types like `List` and `ArrayList`.

Comment: You should fix proper indentation in your example.

Comment: @David Conrad please elaborate what to use instead of that???

Comment: You should use parameterized types, such as (in this case) `HashMap<Integer, List<String>>`, `List<String>`, and `ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: thanx I will do the same...

Comment: @David Conrad can You help me regarding memory leak in java

Comment: Ask a question about it here on SO. If I'm not able to help you, someone else will.

Comment: @David Conrad : I am trying to track the memory leak in JBOSS server by working on its historical data. I calculated the Avg. value for each day over a 60 days period and then trying to see the trends to track the memory leak.Actually I want to see if there is gradual increase in memory usage despite of Full GC then it may lead to server crash and this may be due to Memory Leak.

Comment: @David Conrad : please suggest me whether I am going in right direction or if not please suggest me how to track Memory leak by peeping into data usage.

Comment: Well, finding an increase in memory usage over time would certainly suggest a memory leak, but then you're going to have to look at heap dumps and look at the code to find *where* you're leaking memory.

Comment: Regarding your x & y question, an Integer is immutable; its contents cannot change. A List is mutable; its contents can change, and when they do, anyone with a reference to it will see those changes.

Comment: Ya I am looking into Heap & permGen both .But I am not getting constant rise in usages instead I am getting some dip then again rise in usages but ultimately usage keep on rising. So by seeing this behavior may I suggest anyone for memory leak on a particular server

Answer (score 1):

You're adding **the same list** to the Map multiple times and clearing it each time, so no surprise that its empty. Solution: Don't clear the list, create a **new** one within the for loop. This way, the Map will hold a unique List for each Integer.

```
public class ListMap {
     HashMap<Integer,List<String>> mp=new HashMap<>();
     // List<String> myList=new ArrayList<String>(); // **** get rid of
    Integer x=0;
    Integer y=5;
    void test(){
        for(Integer i=0;i<5;i++){
            List<String> myList=new ArrayList<String>();  // ****** here 
            x=y;
            myList.add("check-1a"+i);
            myList.add("check-1a"+i+1);
            y=null;
            System.out.println(x);//output=5
            mp.put(i,myList);
            // myList.clear();  // **** get rid of
        }
   }
```

Also as per Tom, don't use raw types if possible, and so declare your lists as `List<String>` and `ArrayList<String>`.

Comment: I handled it but I am unable to understand why the values of List that I put inside the map prior to clearing the list ,clears the values inside the map as well

Comment: @ShashiRanjan: you handled what?? You're only creating **one** List and re-adding this single same **cleared** List multiple times. Don't do this. The key concept being that there is only **one** ArrayList object in all your original code.

Comment: and in similar way I used two objects X & Y and putting NULL inside the Y object then why X contains the previous values of Y ???

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels `Don't do this.` ... since you've mentioned that ... how about your usage of raw types (`HashMap` and `List`/`ArrayList`)? :P

Comment: @Tom: fair enough. Fixed.

Comment: @ShashiRanjan: for your x and y problem, post a compilable and runnable example program that demonstrates your issue, a program **with** a main method.

Comment: @ShashiRanjan `x` and `y` in your code are just variables holding object *references*, not objects. When you write `x=y`, you're making `x` point to the same `Integer` object as `y`. Then, when you set `y` to `null`, you're setting that variable so that it points to no object. `x` still contains the reference to the object previously referenced by `y`.

Comment: @ShashiRanjan: please don't vandalize my answer. If you have further questions, comment please.

Answer (score 1):

When you add an object to a map (or any other collection), you are adding a *reference* to that object, not a copy. When you then make changes to the object, these changes will also affect the references in the map.

When you want to store a *copy* of your list, you need to create a `new` one. This can be done like this:

```
mp.put(i, new ArrayList(myList));
```

An alternative (and in my opinion even better) solution would be to reinitialize myList in the beginning of each loop iteration by setting it to a fresh list object:

```
myList = new ArrayList();
myList.add("check-1a"+i);
myList.add("check-1a"+i+1);
mp.put(i,myList);
```

Note that the list doesn't get destroyed when you reinitialize the variable `myList`. You can think of the object living on inside the map*.

<sub>*although a more technically accurate description would be "the object lives on in memory and isn't garbage-collected as long as there is still a reference to it stored in the map"</sub>